# Send user to page on mobile app when clicking email link

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have just started an `Ionic 2` mobile app.

I am setting up an `update password` process where a user can enter their email, click a "send password update email" button which then emails them a link. They can click that link which takes them to a page where they can update their password.

How do I send them a link in their email that when clicked on will open up the app and take them to a specific page?

Even more complicated is that I have a web app also. So if I'm sending them an email, should I show `update password on website` and `update password on mobile app` links? Or should I just add a link to the website?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ??

Answer (score 2):

In order to open the mobile app from a link, you need to integrate a cordova plugin called [cordova-plugin-customurlscheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme). With this plugin you can register a custom url "protocol" that is unique to your app (eg. myAwesomeApp://register?token=123). After installing the plugin with your custom url, clicking on any link starting with myAwesomeApp:// will open your app and also trigger a function hooked on the window object called handleOpenUrl which accepts the url as param. Inside there you can do your routing, depending on the url param.

```
let self = this;
(<any>window).handleOpenURL = function handleOpenURL(url) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (url && url.indexOf('\register') !== -1) {
      let token = URLHelper.getParameterByName(url, 'token');
      self.setAsRoot(ConfirmEmailPage, { activationToken: token });
    }
  }, 0);
};
```

As for dealing with your web app, what you could do is the following (this is what I am currently doing):

Host online a page (say www.myAwesomeWebsite.com/register?token=123) that checks to see if the user is coming from a mobile device (iOS or Android more specifically). If so on page load redirect them to your myAwesomeApp://register?token=123 link and have a button saying install app from app store with a link to your mobile app. If the user has the app, the app will be opened by the redirect, if they don't they will get an alert saying link cannot be found or sth and after clicking ok they will see the install App from app store button. If the user is not coming from a mobile device, just redirect them to your web app myAwesomeWebApp.com/register?token=123.

Another option is to use a third party service for deep linking like [branch](https://branch.io)

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: Since I posted this answer Ionic team has come with their own plugin for deep linking that kind of simplifies some of the hooking up inside your app. Their detailed blog post can be found [here](http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/). In essence you install their plugin:

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=ionichats --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=ionic-hats.com
```

and then hook to it like so:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, Nav, ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Deeplinks} from 'ionic-native';

import {AboutPage} from './pages/about/about';
import {HatDetailPage} from './pages/hat/hat';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
})
class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

  constructor(private _platform: Platform) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      Deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
        '/about-us': AboutPage,
        '/hats/:hatId': HatDetailPage
      });
    });
  }
});

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

Note that although this improves the plugin interfacing a bit, it does not change the fact that you have to use some other mechanism to handle deep links in conjunction with your web app.

Comment: do you have a working example of this problem. I am also trying to implement exact same thing. Its not working for me.

Comment: what is the package for 'URLHelper'? I can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: Oh sorry if that confused you. URLHelper is just a custom class I wrote to parse urls. You would need something similar.

Comment: I have one related question, when specifying the host for the ionic deeplinking plugin should we add two different hosts one with www and one without www or use *.mydomain.com in case when our website support both? or just specifying mydomain.com should be sufficient (doesn't seem to work in my case)?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed ionic-deep-links plugins does not accept wildcards currently. You will have to specify each subdomain you are using.

Comment: Ok, just for the clarification, specifying mydomain.com wont work for www.mydomain.com correct?